# CSS & HTML- Carousel positioning text below image

Tags: html, css

How do i get the text to appear below each image within the carousel? currently it is appearing to the right hand side.

```
<div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "fullscreen": true, "lazyLoad": 2, "pageDots": false }'>
<img class="carousel-image" data-flickity-lazyload = 'img src here'  
  ondblclick="location.href='#'" /> 
<div class="carousel-cell">text here</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
current CSS:

```
.carousel-image {
  display: block;
  height: 550px;  
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: You should add your CSS, if you applied any. That's how you would have that behaviour for your HTML items.

Answer (score 0):

*Removed flickity-flock-gibberish, and used a sample image.*

Flex will achieve laying out elements easily, and will also take care of centering.

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: .5em;
  border: 1px solid red; /* For testing: remove this */
}

.carousel-image {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <img class="carousel-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png" /> 
  <div class="carousel-cell">text here</div>
</div>
```